# How to download pdf file from chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

I need to download [this](https://amaoed.app.box.com/s/90b2xgu0gdd0gr9em47z0tgw1bda494h) pdf file. Tried all the ways I know, like as follows:

[pdf file](https://m.box.com/shared_item/https%3A%2F%2Fwww.box.com%2Fs%2F90b2xgu0gdd0gr9em47z0tgw1bda494h) (opening download icon in new tab will just say "Sorry, we couldn't find that page"

[Chrome Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/qdsluD3m8IE) ("Right click > Save as" doesn't work)

Comment: Just reading how that link is assembled, I don't trust it as far as I can throw it...

Answer (score 1):

#### I need to download this pdf file.

That is not possible as there is no PDF file to download.

Your link **renders** a PDF server-side and displays it **in the page html**.

It does not serve a PDF file.